# How to run AngularJs html5mode on ASP.Net Core using URL Rewrite?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, url-rewriting, html5mode

I have an angularjs app running on .net framework. when i try to run it on .net core, i cannot fix the html5mode fallback on refreshing the page gets error 404

I already tried to create a web.config for url rewrite and creating a middleware.

```
   <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

I want to run angularjs html5mode on .net core using URL Rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your project, create a xml file like **IISUrlRewrite.xml** and copy paste the configuration

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Then on your **Startup.cs** `Configure()` read that file and attach it on RewriteOptions().AddIISUrlRewrite

```
   using (StreamReader iisUrlRewriteReader = File.OpenText("IISUrlRewrite.xml"))
   {
            var rules = new RewriteOptions();

            rules.AddIISUrlRewrite(iisUrlRewriteReader);

            app.UseRewriter(rules);
   }
   app.UseFileServer();
```

source reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2)